# Что выполняет данная строка?(Это работа с 16-ричными переменными)

Tags: python

```
h0 = 0x67452301
h0 = h0 + a & 0xffffffff
```

Я так понимаю, что это работа с 16 переменными?

Comment: Вообще не понятно без контекста. Какая-то чушь с хексами. ;)

Comment: В данном коде к числу h0 = 1732584193 прибавляется остаток от a при делении на 2^32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это кусок кода подсчёта алгоритма вычисления хэша SHA-1

поскольку в питоне целые числа неограниченной длины, а в алгоритме используются 32 битные числа, то чтобы оставаться в диапазоне 32 битных чисел числа обрезаются

```
a & 0xffffffff
```

как раз выполняет функцию "обрезки" любого числа до 4 байт (32 бит)

т.е. вместо алгоритма

```
h0 += a
```

используется алгоритм, который не даёт числу улезть за нужный диапазон значений

хотя на мой взгляд более правильным было бы сделать так:

```
h0 += a
h0 &= 0xffffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну присваивает хекс значение (`0x67452301`) переменной `h0` потом выполняет сложение с `a & 0xffffffff`, что без контекста не понятно зачем и т.д.

@EzikBro:

> В данном коде к числу `h0 = 1732584193` прибавляется остаток от `a` при делении на `2^32`

Comment: мб это попытка работы с адресом переменной? Я не знаю как в питоне это возможно, но типо автор как в СИ пробовал взять адрес и с ним работать?

Comment: @Cowboyserg В питоне нет всех этих ссылок с указателями.